# Getting server absolute path in .NET core 2.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have ready many articles on the internet and they all suggest to use inject IHostingEnvironment as a dependency.

But my problem is that I have a singleton based class which is not a controller and it loads a file based resource and maintains it as cache. How do I get correct path for it to work?

I have tried to use File.IO also changed program.cs to use UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) but it didn't work.

Comment: @Fred I couldn't do this way because I have no knowledge of Singleton like this. I passed path variable on each constructor of controller. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can still dependency inject a `IHostingEnvironment` into a singleton. Just register the singleton with the DI as a singleton service.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add application services.
    services.AddSingleton<IFileService, FileService>();
}
```